# Similar a array_slice de PHP en Python para Diccionarios

Tags: php, python

Buen día, resulta que tengo éste código en
**php**

```
$array = ["a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3];
$slice = array_slice($array, 1, 2, False);
```

Y quiero transcribirlo en **python**, pero no encuentro ninguna alternativa en la documentación de python. La función de PHP lo que hace es obtener dos Keys y las busca en un array, como

```
list[1:2]
```

en python, pero en los diccionarios resulta en un **KeyError**

Comment: ¿Cómo tenes definido `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos cosas:

- El `array_slice` de PHP no tiene la misma semántica que los slices de python, pues en éstos últimos los números entre corchetes son el índice de inicio, y el índice de fin más uno. En cambio en PHP los parámetros son el índice de inicio y el número de términos a extraer.
- Esta es más grave. En PHP parece que los arrays tipo "diccionario" tienen un orden intrínseco, ya que puedes referirte a conceptos como "el primer elemento del diccionario", "el segundo elemento", etc. En Python, hasta hace bien poco, los diccionarios no tienen orden interno. No hay forma de decir cuál es el primer elemento de un diccionario (el resultado no es determinista) y por tanto no se puede extraer un *slice* basado en los índices.

  En la versión 3.7 los diccionarios sí tenían un orden: el orden de inserción. Es decir, el orden en que se van añadiendo elementos al diccionario. No obstante, este orden era un "efecto secundario" de la forma en que estaban implementados, y la documentación recomendaba no escribir código que dependiera de ese orden, pues eso podría cambiar en versiones futuras.

  En la versión 3.8 los diccionarios ya tienen un orden "oficialmente". Todas las versiones a partir de la 3.8 respetarán este principio, por lo que ya es posible escribir código que dependa de esa ordenación. Igual que en la 3.7, el orden es el de inserción.

Dicho todo lo anterior ¿podemos emular la función `array_slice` de PHP? Pues sí, podemos escribir una función que retorne los elementos de un diccionario comenzando en el i-ésimo. Pero ten en cuenta que cuál es el elemento i-ésimo no es determinista a menos que estés usando Python 3.7 o superior.

La cosa sería así:

- Convertimos el diccionario en una lista de tuplas, usando `diccionario.items()`. Cada elemento de esta lista es una pareja clave-valor.
- En esa lista ya podemos aplicar un *slice* de python, para elegir los elementos que estén entre el i-ésimo hasta el i-ésimo más la longitud solicitada.
- La lista resultante la volvemos a convertir en diccionario y lo retornamos.

```
def dict_slice(d, inicio, longitud):
  lista = list(d.items())[inicio:inicio+longitud]
  return dict(lista)
```

Y un ejemplo de uso:

```
>>> ejemplo = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> dict_slice(ejemplo, 1, 2)
{'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```